# Calculating the maximum of selected rows

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

The `head` of my data frame looks the following:

```
structure(list(wbcode = c("ARG", "ARG", "ARG", "ARG", "ARG", 
"ARG", "ARG", "ARG", "ARG", "ARG", "ARG", "ARG", "ARG", "ARG", 
"ARG", "ARG", "ARG", "ARG", "ARG", "ARG", "ARG", "ARG", "ARG", 
"ARG", "ARG", "ARG"), End = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1982, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1991, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1995, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), LS = c(0.958041958041958, 1.20320197044335, 1.16087598763312, 
0.354430888167198, 0.0475120757386165, 0.0236186492578896, 0.0916911204214743, 
0.14338253921938, 0.408800511837039, 0.385495983810026, 0.244688077879152, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.23774478543667, 1.06301680926773, 0.670834486120376, 
0.60283371506345, 0.437946526596944, 0.468570146238378, 0.30623825822946, 
0.0241300985598649, 0.0201213236433166, 0.0223558659752478), 
    year = c("1974", "1975", "1976", "1977", "1978", "1979", 
    "1980", "1981", "1982", "1983", "1984", "1985", "1986", "1987", 
    "1988", "1989", "1990", "1991", "1992", "1993", "1994", "1995", 
    "1996", "1997", "1998", "1999")), row.names = c(NA, -26L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

What I want to achieve is to create a new column `LS_max` that contains the maximum value of `LS` that is between `year` and `End` (If `End` exists). The resulting data frame would look like this:

```
# A tibble: 26 x 4
#   wbcode   End     LS year   LS_max
#   <chr>  <dbl>   <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
# 1 ARG       NA  0.958  1974   NA
# 2 ARG       NA  1.20   1975   NA
# 3 ARG       NA  1.16   1976   NA
# 4 ARG       NA  0.354  1977   NA
# 5 ARG       NA  0.0475 1978   NA
# 6 ARG       NA  0.0236 1979   NA
# 7 ARG     1982  0.0917 1980   0.409
# 8 ARG       NA  0.143  1981   NA
# 9 ARG       NA  0.409  1982   NA
#10 ARG       NA  0.385  1983   NA
#11 ARG       NA  0.245  1984   NA
#12 ARG       NA  NA     1985   NA
#13 ARG       NA  NA     1986   NA
#14 ARG       NA  NA     1987   NA
#15 ARG       NA  NA     1988   NA
#16 ARG     1991  NA     1989   1.24
#17 ARG       NA  1.24   1990   NA
#18 ARG       NA  1.06   1991   NA
#19 ARG       NA  0.671  1992   NA
#20 ARG       NA  0.603  1993   NA
#21 ARG       NA  0.438  1994   NA
#22 ARG     1995  0.469  1995   0.469
#23 ARG       NA  0.306  1996   NA
#24 ARG       NA  0.0241 1997   NA
#25 ARG       NA  0.0201 1998   NA
#26 ARG       NA  0.0224 1999   NA
```

Please note that the original data frame contains more than one type of `wbcode`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be implemented by aggregating a self join using a complex condition.

This left joins to each row of the `a` instance of `DF` to all rows of the `b` instance of `DF` having the same `wbcode` and satisfying the `between` condition.
Then for each `a` row in the result we take the maximum of the joined `LS` values from `b`.

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select a.*, max(b.LS) as LS_max 
  from DF a 
  left join DF b on a.wbcode = b.wbcode and b.year between a.year and a.End
  group by a.rowid")
```

giving:

```
   wbcode  End         LS year    LS_max
1     ARG   NA 0.95804196 1974        NA
2     ARG   NA 1.20320197 1975        NA
3     ARG   NA 1.16087599 1976        NA
4     ARG   NA 0.35443089 1977        NA
5     ARG   NA 0.04751208 1978        NA
6     ARG   NA 0.02361865 1979        NA
7     ARG 1982 0.09169112 1980 0.4088005
8     ARG   NA 0.14338254 1981        NA
9     ARG   NA 0.40880051 1982        NA
10    ARG   NA 0.38549598 1983        NA
11    ARG   NA 0.24468808 1984        NA
12    ARG   NA         NA 1985        NA
13    ARG   NA         NA 1986        NA
14    ARG   NA         NA 1987        NA
15    ARG   NA         NA 1988        NA
16    ARG 1991         NA 1989 1.2377448
17    ARG   NA 1.23774479 1990        NA
18    ARG   NA 1.06301681 1991        NA
19    ARG   NA 0.67083449 1992        NA
20    ARG   NA 0.60283372 1993        NA
21    ARG   NA 0.43794653 1994        NA
22    ARG 1995 0.46857015 1995 0.4685701
23    ARG   NA 0.30623826 1996        NA
24    ARG   NA 0.02413010 1997        NA
25    ARG   NA 0.02012132 1998        NA
26    ARG   NA 0.02235587 1999        NA
```

Comment: Your code indeed works. I'm not an expert in sql, therefore maybe you are so kind to add some clarification. Does the ```group by a.rowid ``` mean that we create a group for every row to which then all rows from the same table are matched that fulfil the conditions, i. e. which years are between the end and year columns of the original table? From that rows we then select the maximum w.r.t. LS?

Comment: Have added some clarification.

Answer (score 1):

An option would be to create a grouping column based on the occurrence of `NA` in the 'End' column, get the `max` of 'LS' and remove the grouping column afterwards

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(wbcode, grp = cumsum(!is.na(End))) %>% 
  mutate(LS_max = max(LS, na.rm = TRUE) * NA^is.na(End))%>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-grp) %>%
  as.data.frame
#   wbcode  End         LS year    LS_max
#1     ARG   NA 0.95804196 1974        NA
#2     ARG   NA 1.20320197 1975        NA
#3     ARG   NA 1.16087599 1976        NA
#4     ARG   NA 0.35443089 1977        NA
#5     ARG   NA 0.04751208 1978        NA
#6     ARG   NA 0.02361865 1979        NA
#7     ARG 1982 0.09169112 1980 0.4088005
#8     ARG   NA 0.14338254 1981        NA
#9     ARG   NA 0.40880051 1982        NA
#10    ARG   NA 0.38549598 1983        NA
#11    ARG   NA 0.24468808 1984        NA
#12    ARG   NA         NA 1985        NA
#13    ARG   NA         NA 1986        NA
#14    ARG   NA         NA 1987        NA
#15    ARG   NA         NA 1988        NA
#16    ARG 1991         NA 1989 1.2377448
#17    ARG   NA 1.23774479 1990        NA
#18    ARG   NA 1.06301681 1991        NA
#19    ARG   NA 0.67083449 1992        NA
#20    ARG   NA 0.60283372 1993        NA
#21    ARG   NA 0.43794653 1994        NA
#22    ARG 1995 0.46857015 1995 0.4685701
#23    ARG   NA 0.30623826 1996        NA
#24    ARG   NA 0.02413010 1997        NA
#25    ARG   NA 0.02012132 1998        NA
#26    ARG   NA 0.02235587 1999        NA
```

Comment: Suppose we set `df1$LS[10] <- 1`  That should not change the answer but it does change the result of this code so it must be wrong.